# Issue in adding syscalls in Android libc

Tags: android, embedded-linux, system-calls, android-6.0-marshmallow, bionic

Please help.
I'm working with Android marshmallow (6.0) source code and I need a linux message queue and shared memory related system call support for an application to port. Formerly I was using Kitkat source code and in that it was working.

**The steps I did for that is:**

1. Added syscalls in /BSP/Bionic/libc/SYSCALLS.TXT
2. Generated asm stubs using gensyscalls.py script.
3. Compiled without error libc but the libc.so generated is not containing the added symbols.

Thanks in advance.

**Syscalls added in /BSP/Bionic/libc/SYSCALLS.TXT:**

- int semctl(int semid, int semnum, int cmd, ...) all
- int semget(key_t key, int nsems, int semflg) all
- int semop(int semid, struct sembuf* sops, size_t nsops) all
- void* shmat(int shmid, const void* shmaddr, int shmflg) all
- int shmctl(int shmid, int cmd, struct shmid_ds* buf) all
- int shmdt(const void* shmaddr) all
- int shmget(key_t key, size_t size, int shmflg) all
- int msgctl(int msqid, int cmd, struct msqid_ds *buf) all
- int msgget(key_t key, int msgflg) all
- int msgrcv(int msqid, void* msgp, size_t msgsz, long int msgtyp, int msgflg) all
- int msgsnd(int msqid, const void* msgp, size_t msgsz, int msgflg) all

Comment: Rather than re-invent the wheel here and create your own kernel and libc changes, you should use `Binder` (message/transaction based exchange) and `ashmem` (shared memory between processes.)  Both are available in all builds of Android and properly handle security and resource management in Android's lifecycle model.

Comment: Thanks Larry,
The application which i'm planning to port needs these. Thats why I'm going with this implementation. Otherwise need to redesign the entire application.Anyway; found a solution by adding the syscalls in libc.maps and rebuilding it.